# Calculate max combination of regex language

Tags: regex

This isn't really a coding question, but hopefully it is within the guide lines. I have a given language `L*` where `L = {pi,po}`.

The question is how many combination I can make with `L*` where the maximum length is 9.

The answer is 31, but i do not know how it got calculated. How is this calculated?

If I should not ask this question here please inform me and I will remove the question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but [cs.se] maybe more appropriate. In any case please define **length** - is `popi` length 4 or 2? Also `L*`, mention it is any concatenation of words from `L` (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: if popi would be 4 we could never achieve 9. So I think it is 2. I will post this question on computer science as you suggested thanks for the suggestion!:)